# How to use multiple workstations on same account?

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS2010 and I have two workstations. A stationary and a laptop. I want to keep those two workstations in sync without having to check in my changes.

Is there any smart way to do so?

Comment: I don't believe so - the "unit" of checkouts, etc, is the workspace, and workspaces are inherently tied to a single machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't seen it already, have a look at shelving support.  It allows you to shelve (mock check-in) files, putting them in temporary storage on the TFS server, and then unshelve (mock check-out) those files, and you can use this to transition code between the two environments.  It's not automated, but it's not checking in either.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried public workspaces?  Not 100% sure it will solve your issue, but it is a way to share a workspace between workstations.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2010/02/04/improvements-to-workspaces-in-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: Those look interesting, but they still seem to be locked to a single computer.